# How to make describe() use a pager like less in Maxima?

Tags: maxima

When typing "? something" (or "describe(something)") in Maxima the output scrolls off the screen and one has to manually page up and down to read it. But, for example, in Sage it is paged through "less". Can I somehow configure Maxima to do the same, i.e. page the help text through "less" (or "more")?

Comment: This is not a programming question. It may fit better on a different web site.

Comment: I have found a workaround: in Sage type, e.g. "maxima.plotdf?" and then sage will page the doc correctly. The only problem with this solution is that one has to run sage at the same time as "pure maxima" session.

Comment: For the record, Maxima doesn't have an output pager capability.